# is it possible to enable linux performance counter to log analytics workspace in Azure?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

looks like currently it's only windows performance counter is supported by terraform?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_datasource_windows_performance_counter
I don't see linux performance counter there, just want confirm with people is it possible to enable through terraform?

Comment: The feature for Linux performance counter does not support currently, see [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3182)

Comment: I use local-exec resource to execute Powershell script which enables linux performance counter. I recommend you to do the same.

Comment: hi Bater55, is it within script of deploy machine? because we don't deploy any actual vms, we just want to deploy this so we can monitor for our customers if they have any vms already